# How can I connect my Java SE program to MS Access DB without using any DSN in win 7 64 bit

Tags: java, ms-access, windows-7, 64-bit

I have tried a lot and visited many forums including Stack Overflow but have failed to find a proper answer to my question.

The condition is simple: I don't want to use a DSN so that the software will run on any machine. However, this is not working for me on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Just giving path to .accdb file in connection string should do the trick? but DSN will be always better

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be able to find the connection string you need at [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/). Here would be a good place to start:

[Connection strings for Access 2007](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007)

Answer (score -1):

Currently Microsoft does not have any 64 bit ODBC drivers available for the Office products.

However, as long as the application that you want to connect to is 32 bit, you can use the 32 bit ODBC drivers to create the DSN. To get to the 32 bit ODBC drivers, the 32 bit Data Source administrator must be used. The 32 bit Data Source administrator must be launched directly if you are using a 64 bit OS. The file should be located at the following path:

c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1 - RE: "Currently Microsoft does not have any 64 bit ODBC drivers available for the Office products." - That is incorrect. There are both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the Access Database Engine (and related drivers) available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).